# REP-56132 Access is denied to the report definition file

Tags: oraclereports

I have been researching this problem for a couple weeks now and at a dead end.

Running 12c form and reports, Linux OEL 6, WebLogic 12c. Also, this is a 6i to 12c migration of all objects. This fails when sending the report directly across in the URL and with web.show_document.

Have added the COMPONENT_CONFIG_PATH, added the suggested changes to rwserver.conf and the rwservlet.properties, all folders and objects are wide open at 0777. I've tried a number of different users with various privileges but all have resulted in the same error. I have tried with RUN_REPORT_OBJECT and that also results in an error of FRM-41219. Here is the rwserver.confg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/reports/server" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <cache class="oracle.reports.cache.RWCache">
      <property name="cacheSize" value="50"/>
   </cache>
   <engine class="oracle.reports.engine.EngineImpl" engLife="1" id="rwEng" maxEngine="1" minEngine="1" maxIdle="3" callbackTime="90000">
       <property name="sourceDir" value="/app01/bcis/forms"/>
       <property name="tempDir" value="/app01/oracle/tmp"/>
       <property name="keepConnection" value="yes"/>
   </engine>
   <engine class="oracle.reports.urlengine.URLEngineImpl" engLife="50" id="rwURLEng" maxEngine="1" minEngine="0"/>
  <!--
   <destination class="oracle.reports.server.DesFile" destype="file"/>
   <destination class="oracle.reports.server.DesCache" destype="cache"/>
   <destination class="oracle.reports.server.DesPrint" destype="printer"/>
  -->
   <destination class="oracle.reports.plugin.destination.ftp.DesFTP" destype="ftp"/>
   <destination class="oracle.reports.plugin.destination.webdav.DesWebDAV" destype="WebDav"/>
   <!--job engineId="rwEng" jobType="report" securityId="Empty"/-->
   <!--job engineId="rwURLEng" jobType="rwurl" securityId="Empty"/-->
   <notification class="oracle.reports.server.MailNotify" id="mailNotify">
      <property name="succnotefile" value="succnote.txt"/>
      <property name="failnotefile" value="failnote.txt"/>
   </notification>
   <jobRepository>
      <property name="dbuser" value="rwadmin"/>
      <property name="dbpassword" value="csf:reports:repo"/>
      <property name="dbconn" value="dcis2d01.mlgw.org:1522:CISDB12"/>
   </jobRepository>
   <connection idleTimeOut="30" maxConnect="250"/>
   <queue maxQueueSize="1000"/>
   <folderAccess>
      <read>/app01/bcis/forms:/app01/bcis/reports:/app01/bcis/dev/exe:/app01/bcis/exe:/app01/oracle/tmp</read>
      <write>/app01/bcis/forms:/app01/bcis/reports:/app01/bcis/dev/exe:/app01/bcis/exe:/app01/oracle/tmp</write>
      <defaultWriteFolder>/app01/bcis/forms</defaultWriteFolder>
   </folderAccess>
   <identifier encrypted="yes">QgZSFEalKUbL0t/KwwqSEg0=</identifier>
   <proxyInfo>
      <proxyServers>
         <proxyServer name="$$Self.proxyHost$$" port="$$Self.proxyPort$$" protocol="all"/>
      </proxyServers>
      <bypassProxy>
         <domain>$$Self.proxyByPass$$</domain>
      </bypassProxy>
   </proxyInfo>
   <pluginParam value="%MAILSERVER_NAME%" name="mailServer"/>
</server>
```

The naming service:

```
<namingService name="Cos" host="10.211.212.164" port="14021"/>
```

I have checked the spelling of all paths, so they are right and they do run under rwrun and I can bring them up in rwbuilder.
If there is anything else that would be helpful, please let me know.
Any suggestions at this point will be helpful and I would appreciate as many quick responses as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the report as an object in the calling form? (Similar to adding a new canvas or new datablock)

The find_report_object call should be passed the name of the report object as it was added to the form. The FRM-41219 makes me think you haven't added the report object. This did *not* need to be done in 6i.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to verify that the reports are generated? You could try trigger generation of a report directly from a curl command on the reports server. I use something like the below URL to verify that the reportsserver is running:

http://reportsserver:port/reports/rwservlet?userid=user/password@tnsname&destype=cache&report=reportnam.rdf&desformat=PDF&argument1=123&argument2=456

Comment: Thanks and yes I have done the above with both rdf and rep and I was finally successful with rdf files but not rep files. I actually ended up creating a new domain and setting up a bare bones reports server and seems to be working fine for rdf files